# "Curious to learn" vs. "curious to learning"

Tags: adjectives, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

I know that in case of "looking forward to" I have to use the gerund form. So e.g.

> I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Now I am not sure about this sentence:

> I am always curious to learning new languages.

Is this correct? Or should I use:

> I am always curious to learn new languages.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective *curious* doesn't really match the idea of learning languages. *Curious* has the implications of asking questions. You could be curious about languages, but probably not about learning languages. (Unless you're curious about the study of language acquisition, but even then your sentence is odd because it has the quantified *always*.) I would say one of these instead:

> I am always eager to learn new languages.
>
> I am always excited to learn new languages.

Comment: Leaving aside the semantics of the example sentence, I believe the actual intended question was whether _curious to_ acts like _eager to_, taking an infinitive; or like _look forward to_, taking a gerund. For this, the answer is of course the former.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah that's right. Although as I said, you can also be *curious about*.

Comment: The "to" is associated with "looking forward," as in "I am looking forward to something happening in the future"; it does not belong with "curious." Once you see that, look at @JanusBahsJacquet's comment.

Comment: @outisnihil Well, you can be curious to do something just fine (“I'd be quite curious to know…” is the most common use I can think of). I wouldn't say it doesn't belong with _curious_; it just doesn't fit semantically in the context of the asker’s example sentence.

Comment: Don't you think those are two completely different uses of "to," though, @JanusBahsJacquet?

Comment: @outisnihil Certainly, yes. Different meanings—one is an actual preposition, the other is just an infinitive marker.